# Customize UINavigationBar.appearance() on ScrollViewDidScroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbarappearance

Is it still possible to customize the navigation bar on `ScrollViewDidScroll` now?

For example:

[image: 1]

Comment: can you provide the video? which kinda appearance do you want in the navigation bar?

Comment: @ShabnamSiddiqui I've edited the post with gif link, I don't have enough reps to embed an image.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change it using:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = False
```

And remove:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage...
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Then modify the `barTintColor` when user scrolls.